# How to change response encoding?

Tags: servicestack-bsd

By default my ServiceStack service returns json responses in UTF-8 encoding. How to change it to ASCII? I think this shouldn't be difficult, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack Serializers are hard-coded to use UTF-8 and can't be changed.